# getting more info from UIImageView with a specific tag

Tags: objective-c, ios

if i have the tag number of my UIImageView is there a way i can get more information pulled about my UIImageView?

For example, could i make a new temporary UIImageView and assign it the view that has the tag number i have?

Im not sure if there is a way to initialize something with just a tag number.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by: *"could i make a new temporary UIImageView and assign it the view that has the tag number i have"*?

Comment: i meant make a new UIImageView and make it equal to the other original UIImageView with tag 2 (or whatever number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag` to retrieve the UIImageView that has the tag. If for example you want to create a new UIImageView with the same image as the original UIImageView, you can't do something like this:

```
UIImageView *originalImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
UIImageView *copyImageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImageView.image];
```

Comment: would something like this work if i had more then one UIView with the same tag number in my self.view.

Comment: @MaxReed - No, if you have many views with the same tag, `viewWithTag` will only return one of them. If you want to access the others too, you will have to loop manually on the subviews (you can get them using the property `subviews` of `UIView`) and check the value of their tag. But you probably should avoid using the same tag for multiple views. Even in the solution I proposed in this comment, how would you be able to differentiate between two images that has the same tag?